# QR codes in java

Tags: java, qr-code

Im looking into trying to incorportate QR codes into my java program. I want them to be the user input and each code will have a numerical value. For example code_A = 1 and code_B = 5 or something like that. Where can i learn how to do this? Or do any of you have any experience incorporating these QR codes into java.

I was thinking maybe setting up a place to store the value of each QR code, maybe storing them as text documents and then when the QR code is read into the program it tells the program to read the value from the text document. Probably not the most effieient way, but so far it seems the most logical way that I can come up with.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you want. A QR code basically is text rendered as 2D bar code so I don't know why you want to store the value as long as you have the code (as long as the codes not just represent ids or shortcuts and need some extra information). A famous library to work with them is [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/).

Comment: @pap my main problem is i dont know where to even start. The coding itself wont be a problem once I can figure out how to have the program read the QR code. I just need to be able to pull the value from the QR and im not sure how to do that.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your aim to use the QR Codes? I should remind you that QR codes themselves can contain text around 4300 characters by themselves, using another document to map the values is not the best way to use a QR Code.

Comment: @his and ive looked into ZXing, i dont wont to build this android. This is going to be a windows application eventually and its the beginning of an idea that ive been incubating for some time now. I decided that instead of trying to just think well would this work or that work, Im going to try and implement different types of input and see which fits best with what Im trying to do. I would explain what I am trying to do, but the last time i did that on a forum site someone stole my idea and made it before i could.

Comment: @bmkorkut i want the QR codes to hold a value, and based off that value the program is going to do different things. the simpliest method being: 
if (code_a == 0)
{
do stuff;
}

not exactly what i plan to do with it, but if i can make it do this than i am off to a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comments on your question say: I dont really get what you are trying to do.

[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) is definitely the right library to use. With it you can create QRCodes as follows.

Quick and dirty example:

```
    // create QR code
    BitMatrix bitMatrix = new QRCodeWriter().encode("Text in QRCode", BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 15, 15);
    // save as image
    String path = "path/on/disc"
    File img = new File(path);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(img);
    MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bitMatrix, "gif", fos);
    fos.close();
```

In the end its your choice what content/source you'll put in this code (as long as it is a String).

**No offense:** You should consider asking questions more general in case you're not able to give or have enough information.

Anyway, I hope this helped! Have Fun!

Comment: Im new to this site and still getting used to how to ask these questions. Words have never been my strong point and sometimes when I try to explain myself, what I am trying to say is lost in how I say it. 

Basically what I am trying to do is use QR codes as a series of buttons. If I have 5 options each one will be linked to its own specific part of the code. For example if I am making a calculator code_A could initiate an add function, code_B could call subtraction, and so on. Is that a little bit clearer?

Comment: A little bit :). I hope we put you on the right track and that you're able to accomplish your goal. Cheers!